# Does any case exist where non-random initial population improves the genetic algorithm result?

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, algorithms, stochastic-calculus

In all Genetic Algorithm (GA) examples that I have observed so far, the initial population is generated randomly. However, is there any case where a pre-defined subset of initial population makes an improvement that is unlikely to be achieved by only randomly generated initial population?

Comment: You can always make improvements to your starting guess but it implies you have some additional information about how to maximize the fitness function a priori. For a trivial example say you know exactly how to maximize the fitness function by other means, then you can choose your starting population to be the best immediately and require zero iterations to maximize the fitness function. The amount of information you have to select a population a priori will vary from problem to problem.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, Any non-trivial example?

Comment: @CyclotomicField, In addition, I am afraid adding some bad solution at the beginning has chance of diverting the GA to local minima.

Comment: For a non-trivial example consider Leela Chess, a real world genetic algorithm to learn and study chess. You could give it the most common opening moves a priori knowing they are well studied and theory is robust. This would be done on faith in human intuition and collective skepticism but with several hundred years of theory it's reasonable to assume it. They did start random and did converge to standard openings.